# change several symlink destinations at once

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

Recently I changed my username in osx following apple documentation.
I have `sh` and `bin` directories under home directory.

Normally I write `sh/foo.sh` and link it to `bin/foo` to use it.

After changing username all symbolic link indicate path that include old username.
Is there way to replace all username in symlinks at once?

The old username is enough long and uniq that doesn't match other strings in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just recreate the symlinks?

```
cd ~/bin; for f in ../sh/*.sh; do ln -sf $f $(basename $f .sh); done
```

Other options:

- `cd ~/bin; find . -lname '/Users/oldname/sh/*' -exec ln -sf ../sh/{}.sh {} \;`
- `cd ~/bin; for f in *; do target=$(readlink $f); [[ $target = /Users/oldname/* ]] && ln -sf ${target/oldname/newname} .; done`

`ln` doesn't overwrite existing files without `-f`. `find -lname` matches the targets of symlinks.